# How do I close the browser (IE8) using Watin?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, watin, coded-ui-tests

I am using Watin 2.0 to develop some automated UI tests. I cannot get Watin to close the browser after it has opened it. The Watin.Core.Browser object implements IDisposible but Dispose() does not do the trick. I have also tried using the Close() method.

Most recently I have tried wrapping the IE object instantiation in a Using statement but no luck.

I am testing with IE8

```
using (IE ie = new IE())
{
    ie.GoTo(ApplicationContainer.SummaryUriProvider.URI);
    Link furthurReadingLink = ie.Link(Find.ByText("Further Reading"));
    furthurReadingLink.Click();

    string subTitle = ie.Div("frheader").Element(Find.ByClass("panelsubtitle")).Text;

    Assert.AreEqual("Further Reading", subTitle);
}
```

Comment: I just checked my Watin tests and I am doing the same thing you are, but IE definitely closes. Are you using the latest version of Watin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if the test throws some exception the dispose is never called.

Answer (score 1):

You also want to be sure that you don't have any *IE developer consoles* (F12) open - it will cause WatiN 2.1 to hang when .Close() is called.

HTH

Comment: Whilst this was not the answer to the original question you solved my issue of WatiN hanging for a good few seconds when disposing.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but have you tried ForceClose():

```
if (ie.NativeBrowser != null)
{
    ie.ForceClose();
}
```

Or to ensure no other instances of IE are open find all open instances and ForceClose() them:

```
while (IE.InternetExplorersNoWait().Count > 0)
{
    var ie = IE.InternetExplorersNoWait()[0];
    ie.ForceClose();
}
```

You can also force the Dispose() method:

```
if (ie.NativeBrowser != null)
{
    ie.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ie.close() worked for me in ie 8

Answer (score 0):

Also, You might want to check your browser `AutoClose` property `ie.AutoClose`